# Running Testng.xml from POM.xml is not running tests in sequence

Tags: java, xml, maven, testng

I am running testng.xml file using POM.xml by adding compiler and surefire plugins. It runs test but the sequence of tests is not as expected.
I have 10 classes mentioned in testng.xml and it runs in that sequence when i run through testng.xml. But when running through POM.xml the sequence goes like; first it runs all the 0 priority tests mentioned in all classes, then 1 priority tests and so on. It should run tests according to the classes sequence mentioned in testng.xml.
Any quick help will be much appreciated.

```
   <build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${jdk.level}</source>
        <target>${jdk.level}</target>  
        
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

 </plugins>

 </build>
```

Comment: The surefire is just a runner for your TestNG XML, we need the XML to understand what the logic inside, also if you added priority for each test that also affects the logic of TestNG, I will recommend reading [TestNG documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) about the running logic

Answer (score 0):

under testng dependency the scope tag needed to be changed to compile from test and it resolved the issue as it needed to compile the build after adding plugins.
It resolved the issue.